# 3D Retro ASCII game taking up 25% CPU, any way to optomize?

Tags: c++, cmd, ascii, frame-rate

I'm working on a Wolfenstein 3D style FPS using Windows Command Prompt and ASCII only.

When I added shading, the program suddenly started taking 25% of my CPU, (1 core), and was running at 2-4 fps. Is there any way I can optimize my code to allow it to run better on my computer?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int nScreenWidth = 120;
int nScreenHeight = 40;

float fPlayerX = 8.0f;
float fPlayerY = 8.0f;
float fPlayerView = 0.0f;

int nMapHeight = 16;
int nMapWidth = 16;

float fFOV = 3.14159 / 4.0;

float fDepth = 16.0f;

int main()
{
wchar_t *screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight];
HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;

std::wstring map;
map += L"#########.......";
map += L"#...............";
map += L"#.......########";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"#......##......#";
map += L"#......##......#";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"###............#";
map += L"##.............#";
map += L"#......####..###";
map += L"#......#.......#";
map += L"#......#.......#";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"#......#########";
map += L"#..............#";
map += L"################";

while (true) {

    if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'A') & 0x8000) {
        fPlayerView -= (0.001f);
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'D') & 0x8000) {
        fPlayerView += (0.001f);
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'W') & 0x8000) {
        fPlayerX += sinf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
        fPlayerY += cosf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'S') & 0x8000) {
        fPlayerX -= sinf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
        fPlayerY -= cosf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < nScreenWidth; x++) {
        float fRayAngle = (fPlayerView - fFOV / 2.0f) + ((float)x / (float)nScreenWidth) * fFOV;

        float fDistanceToWall = 0;
        bool bHitWall = false;

        float fEyeX = sinf(fRayAngle);
        float fEyeY = cosf(fRayAngle);

        while (!bHitWall && fDistanceToWall < fDepth) {
            fDistanceToWall += 0.1f;

            int nTestX = (int)(fPlayerX + fEyeX * fDistanceToWall);
            int nTestY = (int)(fPlayerY + fEyeY * fDistanceToWall);

            if (nTestX < 0 || nTestX >= nMapWidth || nTestY < 0 || nTestY >= nMapHeight) {
                bHitWall = true;
                fDistanceToWall = fDepth;
            } else {
                if (map[nTestY * nMapWidth + nTestX] == '#') {
                    bHitWall = true;
                }
            }
        }

        int nCeiling = (float)(nScreenHeight / 2.0) - nScreenHeight / ((float)fDistanceToWall);
        int nFloor = nScreenHeight - nCeiling;

        short nShade = ' ';
        short fShade = ' ';

        if (fDistanceToWall <= fDepth / 4.0f)           nShade = 0x2588;    // Very close   
        else if (fDistanceToWall < fDepth / 3.0f)       nShade = 0x2593;
        else if (fDistanceToWall < fDepth / 2.0f)       nShade = 0x2592;
        else if (fDistanceToWall < fDepth)              nShade = 0x2591;
        else                                            nShade = ' ';

        for (int y = 0; y < nScreenHeight; y++) {
            if (y < nCeiling) {
                screen[y * nScreenWidth + x] = ' ';
            }
            else if (y > nCeiling && y <= nFloor) {
                screen[y * nScreenWidth + x] = nShade;
            }
            else {
                float b = 1.0f - (((float)y - nScreenHeight / 2.0f) / ((float)nScreenHeight / 2.0f));
                if (b < 0.25)       fShade = '#';
                else if (b < 0.5)   fShade = 'x';
                else if (b < 0.75)  fShade = '.';
                else if (b < 0.9)   fShade = '-';
                else                fShade = ' ';
                screen[y * nScreenWidth + x] = fShade;
            }
            
        }

    }

    screen[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight - 1] = '\0';
    WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight, { 0, 0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if no key is pressed?  Your program executes the `for` loop: `for (int x = 0; x < nScreenWidth; x++)` regardless of whether a key is pressed or not.  For every cycle of the `while` loop, which could be thousands, when there is no keyboard activity, that entire `for` is executed, so no wonder things may seem "slow".

Comment: This code is the equivalent of doing a hard burn out while waiting for the next destination. Set up a proper event loop that waits for keyboard input. Windows has events for these you can hook into.

Comment: Also, if you had debugged the code and put a breakpoint at the start of the `for` loop, you would have seen that it is being executed over and over again, all without touching the keyboard once.  So you basically have a tight `while` loop that doesn't do any sort of "yielding", and inside that loop, a `for` loop that executes for no reason if the keyboard isn't utilized.

Comment: How to fix it -- I think you should invest the time to research proper event-driven techniques and possibly some multithreading basics when it comes to programming anything in Windows that deals with issues like this.  It isn't as simple as writing a "serialized" programming, where things just run top-down (your program indicates this is how you approached things).

Comment: Off-topic:  If you change your `float` types to `double` (let's say to improve precision), will you change the variable names or believe that Hungarian notation lies.

Answer (score 0):

I would make smth like below, this is not tested.

```
const HANDLE stdin_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

while (true) {
    bool is_moving = false;

    if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'A') & 0x8000) {
        fPlayerView -= (0.001f);
        is_moving  = true;
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'D') & 0x8000) {
        fPlayerView += (0.001f);
        is_moving  = true;
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'W') & 0x8000) {
        fPlayerX += sinf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
        fPlayerY += cosf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
        is_moving  = true;
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'S') & 0x8000) {
        fPlayerX -= sinf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
        fPlayerY -= cosf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
        is_moving  = true;
    }

    if (!is_moving) {
        WaitForSingleObject(stdin_handle, 100);
        continue;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < nScreenWidth; x++) {
```

Comment: This somewhat worked, its now faster when looking at an object closer to the player. But when looking at an object farther out, the performance issues returned.

Comment: *This somewhat worked, its now faster when looking at an object closer to the player.* -- Then you need to profile your code to see exactly where the slowdown is.  You still are using a tight `while(true)`, even though the `for` loop is now only executed when the keyboard is actually used.